# Exporting Data in X,Y,Z format

Tags: excel

I have a number of Excel files containing coordinate data that is not normalized.
A single row describes multiple points.

Invariably, one column gives the X value. As an illustration some files have say 3 columns representing Z values, and one column representing Y.

```
 X Y1 Y2 Y3 Z
```

Other files have Multiple Y and Z columns in which point sets may share Y or Z columns.

There may be as many as 40 columns in a table and there are usually about 300 rows.

I need to export the data in CSV format with X, Y, Z values. Is there some relatively simple way to generate a sheet containing X, Y, Z coordinates from such data so that it can be exported?

So that
      X Y1 Y2 Y3 Z

becomes

```
 X, Y1, Z  ; multiple rows
 x, Y2, Z  ; multiple rows
 X, Y3, Z  ; multiple rows
```

Such that the x and z values are repeated one for each set of Y values.

There is one other format that I have to deal convert. One column contains the X, values, one Row contains the y values, and the z values are in the row and column with the X and Y value.

Complicating all this is that there may be omitted or missing values in some of the cells.

This appears to be the same problem in python

[Convert datafiles 'X' 'Y' 'Z' 'data' format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363144/convert-datafiles-x-y-z-data-format)

In response to ANDY:

A sheet may be laid out as columns:

```
X  Y1 Y2 Z1 Y3 Y4 Y5 Z2
```

The coordinate sets are:

```
X, Y1, Z1
X, Y2, Z1
X, Y3, Z2
X, Y4, Z2
```

Comment: Are you only looking to use excel to make this conversion or are you looking for a programmatic solution? Any particular language?

Comment: I'd like to do it in excel. Vba is OK.

Comment: Can you give an example of data having Multiple Y and Z columns in which point sets may share Y or Z columns?

Comment: I'd do it in VBA with a for loop.  There may be a complicated and fancy option like the link you've supplied, but a for loop seems like maybe twenty minutes of coding.

Comment: Do these columns contain a header by which you can determine if it's an X, Y, or Z coordinate? If so, what does that header look like?

Comment: No, the columns contain a textual description from which you have to determine whether it is X, Y, Z. That has to be done manually.

Comment: @user3344003 You say "Invariably, one column gives the X value. As an illustration some files have say 3 columns representing Z values, and one column representing Y." Did you mean "3 columns representing Y values, and one column representing Z"?

Comment: And I take it that your example should also have `X, Y5, Z2` as the last row?

Comment: Also, your answer to JVevill's question confuses me. *How* do you determine which columns contain Z coordinates? What is it about the header that makes you think "Ah, these two columns here are Zeds"? Would be good to see an example that more closely resembles your actual problem.

Comment: You have to read the text above the columns and use some common sense as to which Y columns apply to which Z columns.